# Баг с отображением полученной репутации

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, репутация

3 октября получил следующее изменение репутации:

- -1 за голос против ответа
- +1 ответ был удален, голос вернулся
- +10 за мой ответ
- -8 - за мой ответ
- +8 - за удаление своего ответа

На табе репутации в header'е это показано просто как +10 за вопрос (до удаления своего ответа было вроде +2) Но при этом вкладка репутации в профиле не учитывает удаление своего ответа.

Т.е. удаление своего ответа повлияло на рейтинг (-8 отменилось), это отобразилось в статистике (в табе header'а), но не отобразилось в статистике профиля

Прошло уже несколько дней, а информация об удаленном ответе так и не отображается (и не учитывается в рейтинге за день на вкладке репутации в профиле)

Скрин профиля на данный момент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление**

У меня за тот день были следующие изменения репутации:

- один мой голос против чужого ответа (-1)
- этот ответ был удален (+1)
- 4 голоса против моего ответа (-8)
- я удалил свой ответ (+8)
- один голос за мой ответ (+10)

Итого общее изменение репутации: +10.

Но репутация за день показывает изменение +2, т.е. репутация за день не учитывает мое удаление моего же ответа (но минусы по нему учитываются) 
если отключить галочку "показывать удаленные ответы", то изменение репутации по моему и чужому удаленному ответу не отображается (т.е. учитывается только голос за мой ответ): +10. То есть получается - система знает, что мой ответ удален, раз не показывает его когда галочка выключена, но когда галочка включена, то не учитывает сам факт удаления в виде возвращенной репутации.

Таким образом, реально, за тот день система считает что "я удалил свой ответ (+8)" не надо показывать, но при этом, насколько понял, репутация вернулась ко мне.

При этом, судя по комментарию PashaPash, для других пользователей мое удаление моего ответа отображается нормально, т.е. показывает+10 (не знаю как там отображается, наверное, так же, как если бы у меня была выключена эта галочка с удаленными ответами).

Comment: Кстати, сегодня почти одни минусы ставил, т.е. их было больше 30 (на скрине видно, что всего у меня засчитано 39 голосов), но вкладка репутации учитывает только 30 голосов (-26, т.к. было удалено 4 ответа, поэтому минусы за них вернулись). Т.е. остальные минусы куда-то пропали. И с голосованием что-то не то: всего 39 голосов, но больше голосовать не могу, т.к. "Вы исчерпали лимит голосований на сегодня; в следующий раз можно будет проголосовать через 7 часов" И сомневаюсь что это кэш, т.к. до этого статистика обновлялась хоть и с задержками, но небольшими, а сейчас уже много времени прошло

Comment: у меня в вашем профиле за 3-е сентября показывается посто +10. скорее всего просто кэш.

Comment: @PashaPash, если это и кэш, то очень странный - почти три недели прошло, а данные за тот день не изменились. Здесь скорее дело в другом: вы видите результат действия других пользователей. Я для вас - другой, поэтому вы видите и результат удаления моего ответа. Я так же вижу результат действий других пользователей. Но я - не другой пользователь, поэтому мое удаление ответа мне не показывается. Мне кажется проблема все-таки в этом

Comment: репутацию хоть вернули?

Comment: @PashaPash, так ее сразу же вроде вернули с удалением ответа. Я в вопросе про это и писал: *На табе репутации в header'е это показано просто как +10 за вопрос (до удаления своего ответа было вроде +2)*. Хотя я только по нотификации ориентируюсь, реальное изменение я не контролировал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В самом низу страницы репутации в профиле, есть галка «показать удаленные сообщения». Если она не выставлена, то поведение меню в верхней части страницы и раздела репутация в профиле должно быть одинаковым.

**Обновление**

Все-таки ошибки нет.

- Когда удаленные сообщения скрыты, вы видите репутацию как-будто этих сообщений не существовало вообще.
- Когда удаленные сообщения отображаются, все события связанные с ними учитываются в контексте дня, когда они произошли.

Таким образом, итоговая репутация за день +10. В случае если вы смотрите на репутацию с учетом отображается удаленных сообщений, то репутация показывается с учетом изменений за день (то есть если вы получили +10 за ответ в один день, а удалили его на следующий, с учетом удаленных сообщений у вас в один день будет +10, а на следующий -10, без отображения удаленных изменений не будет вообще).

Более того, в зависимости от типа учётной записи могут опускаться какие-либо события.

Что касается конкретно упомянутого случая, то тут просто забавная ситуация получилось.

[image: img]

Если посмотреть на предыдущий день, то можно увидеть, что именно этот вопрос получил +10 (голос за), затем -2 (голос против), в после этого, в день удаления, еще -8 (4 голоса против). Таким образом, суммарное количество баллов за вопрос к моменту удаления равнялись нулю.

Comment: аха, если убрать галку, то показывает верно. Но это лишь подтверждает мои догадки: вопрос, удаленный мною, не учитывается в статистике, при этом мой вопрос, удаленный другими, отображается нормально (например, [этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/193466/5079)). Т.е. проблема все равно есть, переключение галочки не исправляет баг, а скрывает его, т.к. в этом случае не принимаются во внимание бажные подсчеты. В итоге получаем два связанных бага: 1) галка не показывает удаленные мною вопросы и 2) при включенной галке репутация считается не правильно. Второе просто следствие первого

Comment: Пожалуйста, не могли бы вы наглядно пояснить мне ошибку в подсчете репутации? Я чуть-чуть запутался.